# Exhaust fan hook up. I only have black and white from source. Please help

Tags: electrical

I am trying to hook up a ceiling exhaust fan. I am going to run 2 switches, light and fan separate. The line in power from box is just 14 ga blk and white. My house was built in 60s. I don't know how to do this since I have no red wire. Electrical is not my strong suite in construction so I need a little guidance.

Answer (score 1):

You're going to need to run new wire, which can be tricky.

**ASSUMPTION - There is a wire from the panel to the switchbox.  If the supply goes directly to the fixture first, then this does not apply!!!**

- Turn off power to the circuit.
- Remove the existing fixture.  See if you can get the mounting box out.
- Feel along the wire and remove the staple attaching the wire to the structure.
- Do the same at the switch box.
- Hopefully, your wire will move now if you pull it gently at one end.
- Take some 14-3 wire and strip a few inches of the outer insulation off. (A dull carpet knife works great!)
- Tie one of the strands of the new wire to one of the old.  Wrap the entire connection in electrical tape.
- Pull the old wire out, and the new wire will follow it in.
- Replace staples to the best of your ability.

If you can't get the wire to move, you're going to have to break and patch the drywall, which can be a pain.

**Wiring**
 - The other wire in your switchbox should be the supply from the panel.
 - Cut two pieces of black wire, and pigtail them to the supply black with an appropriate sized wire nut. (You are splitting the wire into two).
 - Wire each end of this pigtail to a separate switch.
 - Wire the 14-3 black to one switch, the red to the other.
 - Wire the whites together with a nut.
 - Connect the ground to the box and the supply ground.
 - Connect the fixture at the other end according to manufacturers instructions.

- Put the switches back in the box with one screw each.  Make sure the connections don't touch.
- Test.
- Reinstall the other screws, faceplates etc.
  [image]
  -

Comment: There should be staples securing the cable every few feet. Using an old cable to pull a new one almost never works, especially if the wiring is original to the home.

Comment: Depends on the length of the run.  However, if the joists are drilled, they won't be stapled.

Comment: Not gonna happen in about 99% of installs. You either work with the wire you have, or you repair drywall.

Comment: @ecnerwal:  that's a huge It Depends. If the wires aren't stapled, and one has access to them eg via the attic, using the old three-conductor wire to pull 4-conductor through the wall to/from the switch is often quite easy. Combine that with a unit which puts two switches in a single-sized box, and you've got what's needed. Did that for a ceiling fan installation; someone had previously done the same for a bathroom light/vent unit which seems to be what the querant is asking about.